# How to clear custom message created by error boundary when I navigate to other router pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am very new to React JS. I want to use error boundary in my application which is using react router which shows links to navigate to different component pages. When I used the error boundary, the custom error message which is added once in a component page is always available in other component pages.
How can I clear the customer error message which is created by the error boundary, when I navigate to other pages(URL)?

Comment: one approach would be to clear the errors on every component did mount or clear the error messages in the onEnter hook of react router

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're can access to your error message (the example is using redux, but not mendatory), with react-router you can access to [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) which will be update each time you change your url..

On your application level you could listen to that history inside you're app.js, (it should be at you're application entry point)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    //listen on url change
    history.listen((location, action) => {
      // clear erorr on location change
      props.dispatch(erorrActions.clear()); // using redux, but you could use you're own provider / sevice

    });
  }
}
```

History must be inject inside your app such as

your history.js:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

Your index.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import { history } from './history';
import { App } from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App/>
    </Router>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```